# Status link gets confused on migrated questions

Tags: bug, migrated-questions

I saw this on the ScienceFiction&Fantasy.SE homepage, and it made me cock my head; the link on questions that typically says "asked X minutes ago" or "modified Y minutes ago" or whatever, doesn't know what happened to this question.

[image]

Clicking into the question, it was originally asked on RPG.SE, and migrated to SFF.

[image]

There's another, similar case from much earlier; this one is missing both the "action" ("asked", "modified", etc.) and the user who performed the action:

[image]

This one was migrated from Movies&TV.SE, and asked by a user who doesn't have an SFF account to link:

[image]

Although I can't personally confirm it, one of the Mods on OpenSource.SE confirms that he sees this a lot when handling migrations on that site:

> I deal with migration to and from Open Source frequently, being a moderator there, and I see this every time.

Comment: I've always seen it like this when migrations happen. So it *does* happen, I'm sure. That whether if it's a bug or not concerns me.

Comment: Likely because it catches the last action in the post history. Also, we [Open Source] deal with a lot of migrations?